# SQL Server Management Studio: The columns in table do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, ssms, foreign-key, primary-key

I have two tables:  Students and Courses.  I want to set a foreign key in the Students table from the couseId column to the courseId column in the Courses table.  I have set primary keys to both courseId columns but Management Studio is still giving me the error The columns in table `'Courses' do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint.'`  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This design doesn't make much sense to me, unless I have the wrong idea of courses - can't a student be enrolled in more than one course?

Comment: Yes, they could.... what determines this to be a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: The fact that you put course id in the student table. How would you represent two courses? By storing the same first name and last name twice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a junction table. I have no idea what the point-and-click UI is doing behind the scenes or how you are getting into this situation but I think this makes more sense:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
  StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ... Other columns ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Courses
(
  CourseID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ... Other columns ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentCourses
(
  StudentID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
      REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
  CourseID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
      REFERENCES dbo.Courses(CourseID),
  PRIMARY KEY(StudentID, CourseID)
);
```

Now, I am not entirely clear why one of your images shows SemesterID as part of the key for one of the tables; I don't know enough about the business logic and how you define courses to guess where that should be. But for the student-course relationship, again unless I have a completely bizarre definition of "course," should not be declared in the Students table.

Also, I wouldn't use the CHAR data type for strings that will clearly have different lengths. You should use varchar (or maybe nvarchar, depending on location and your school's educational domain) for course name, and nvarchar for proper names.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSMS, right click on the field you want to set as your Primary Key.
From the options in the displayed dialog box, choose SET AS PRIMARY KEY.

You can not have two primary keys in the same table, but you can have more than two foreign keys in same table.

From your table, you set two primary keys in the same table which is wrong. You have to cancel one of them.

Then for your foreign key, you can't set your foreign key like you do in Primary key but can create a relationship defining it.

To do this, create your other table containing the Foreign key, set your primary key in the newly created table.

Click on the field containing the data you know or choose as your foreign key.

Right click on it, select RELATIONSHIP. CREATE RELATIONSHIP.

A box would display. Click on ADD, another box would display.

Select Tables and Column Specification by clicking on the small +sign in a small box by the Tables and Column Spec in the Foreign Key Relationship box.

Click on the small option box at the end of the Table and Column spec displayed ....

A new window will appear, select the table for your primary key as your foreign key table is already set cos you started this from your foreign key table.

When the primary table is set, select your primary key from the options menu provided by the key space.

Select your foreign key. Click ok.

From Object Explorer, right click on Database Diagram,
Create a new database diagram.
Make sure your user under security setting is not Login user with password under User Type in the SQL server setting there.

From the database diagram created, refresh the diagram, add by selecting any table you worked with, refresh again then add again by selecting the other table you worked with. The two tables containing the primary and foreign keys. Click ok.

Your table displays in diagram form.

You execute it, you have to do some inserting.

Go to Tables, click on the diagram file, right click, select create script, select insert to, click ok.

Then go on with your codes.